# How to wait until GET request response

Tags: javascript, html

I try to create a html template which shows some Plotly graphs after fetch data from spesific URL with GET response.

It had to be very basic operation but it did not.

I can't able to stop java-script execution until the response return.

Internet suggest use async-await an I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function graphDrawFunction() {

                var request = async () => {
                    var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/log');
                    return await response.json();
                }
                var data = request();

                for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

                    // Some calculations generates traces and layouts from data for graphs
                    //var trace = function test1(data)
                    //var layout = function test2(data)

                    var section = document.getElementById('graphContainer');
                    var plotlyDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    plotlyDiv.id = "graph" + String(Math.random());
                    section.appendChild(plotlyDiv);

                    Plotly.plot(plotlyDiv.id, trace, layout);

                }

                return "--"
            };
        </script>
    </head>
<body onload="graphDrawFunction();">

<h1>Report</h1>
<div id="graphContainer">**********</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This thing not works because async not return response.json() as I expected.

So I did different thing:

```
function graphDrawFunction() {

    var request = async () => {
        var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/log');
        var data = await response.json();

        for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

            // Some calculations generates traces and layouts from data for graphs
            //var trace = function test1(data)
            //var layout = function test2(data)

            var section = document.getElementById('graphContainer');
            var plotlyDiv = document.createElement("div");
            plotlyDiv.id = "graph" + String(Math.random());
            section.appendChild(plotlyDiv);

            Plotly.plot(plotlyDiv.id, trace, layout);

            }

        return "--"
    }
};
```

But this did not work too.

So I need help.

More info about project:

My goal is creating a report program. User can filter data and create reports from data. I use Plotly Dash and Flask.

First, Python-Dash fetch the data from SQL. The user then filters the data with a few buttons provided by Dash. This is happening on Python side. Then Flask serve the data on http://127.0.0.1/log. So anything that want to use the data just need to send GET request.

When user click to the create report button a new tab opened with the template I wrote above. You know the story after this.

If there is more appropriate way to do this feel free to say
I don't know much about Web programming

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try like this**

```
           async function graphDrawFunction() {

            var request = async () => {
                var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/log');
                return response.json();
            }
            var data = await request();

            for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

                // Some calculations generates traces and layouts from data for graphs
                //var trace = function test1(data)
                //var layout = function test2(data)

                var section = document.getElementById('graphContainer');
                var plotlyDiv = document.createElement("div");
                plotlyDiv.id = "graph" + String(Math.random());
                section.appendChild(plotlyDiv);

                Plotly.plot(plotlyDiv.id, trace, layout);

            }

            return "--"
        };
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using your first example:

Since `request` is an `async` function, unless you call it with `await`, it will run asynchronously.

Therefore, `graphDrawFunction()` can be written like this:

```js
function graphDrawFunction() {

    var data = (await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/log')).json();

    for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      // ....
    }

    return "--"
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" error. Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: @techebTest My bad, I have edited the answer. It did need a pair of brackets to surround (await fetch(...)). It should work now.

Comment: thanks worked. It returns Promise but when I added another await with brackets it returns real data.
(await (await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/log')).json());
Javascript still suprise me :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the documentation of fetch api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

The await is just to wait for the response, once response is set, you should be able to access it in `response.json()` like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function graphDrawFunction() {

                var request = async () => {
                    var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/log');
                    return response.json();
                }
                var data = request();

                for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

                    // Some calculations generates traces and layouts from data for graphs
                    //var trace = function test1(data)
                    //var layout = function test2(data)

                    var section = document.getElementById('graphContainer');
                    var plotlyDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    plotlyDiv.id = "graph" + String(Math.random());
                    section.appendChild(plotlyDiv);

                    Plotly.plot(plotlyDiv.id, trace, layout);

                }

                return "--"
            };
        </script>
    </head>
<body onload="graphDrawFunction();">

<h1>Report</h1>
<div id="graphContainer">**********</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but the data variable is a Promise when I use your solution and I can't able to get real data from Promise.